# Why do both `htons` and `ntohs` exist?

Tags: c, posix, endianness

I am not sure why `htons` and `ntohs` both exist in the standard library. They do exactly the same thing -- unless I'm confused somehow!

The same goes for `htonl` and `ntohl`.

Answer (score 8):

They make for self-documenting code that tells the reader whether the data is in host- or network- order.

Answer (score 7):

This is in case a machine has some sort of unusual [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) besides big-endian or little-endian that isn't one or more simple byte swaps.

For example, if the value `0x0A0B0C0D` was represented internally as `0B 0C 0D 0A`, then passing this representation to `htonl` would return `0x0A0B0C0D` but `ntohl` would return `0x0C0D0A0B`.

I'm not aware of any platforms that have such a representation, but the presence of separate functions for host-to-network and network-to-host allows for the possibility.

Comment: I was thinking of this case as well, but refrained from writing an answer as ***asymmetric*** byte order is something for eccentric chip designers on dope ... ;-)